# How to best push a lot of WiFi data to LED christmas lights?

Tags: http, post, tcp, udp, iot

I'm tinkering with hardware as follows:  an ESP32 chip that can control a 5M run of 144-per-meter LEDs (720 total).  Each has Wifi, and I have a web server up and running on a bunch of them and the clocks synchronized to within a few microseconds with a local NTP server.

Let's say I have 10 of them and want to treat them like a big long Christmas light display.  I'd want to push data to each of them representing their portion (720 pixels) of the total display (7200 pixels).

The simplest way is to HTTP POST a JSON-encoded version of the data, but that feels very wrong in terms of overhead.  I'd guess a binary UDP blob is likely more appropriate.

What do you think is the best way to send the data to each little wifi webserver?

The amount of data might be something like:

720 pixels x 3 bytes per pixel x 30 frames per second = 64K/sec

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why someone would downvote this, but a suitably useful answer would be:

WebSockets